# Access first line only when output has two lines in R

Tags: r

I am using a package in R called linkcomm and here's the documentation for it https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/linkcomm/linkcomm.pdf

This is what I run so far

```
library(linkcomm) 

g <- read.table("sample.txt", header = FALSE)
lc <- getLinkCommunities(g)  

mc=meta.communities(lc, hcmethod = "ward.D2", deepSplit = FALSE)
cc <- getCommunityCentrality(x, type = "commconn")  

tmp = head(sort(cc, decreasing = TRUE)) 
print(tmp)  
Output: 1e+14  5712365  12815415   511042  12815383   512594 
  3388.230 1493.165 1375.577 1350.684  1312.197   1302.445
```

Now the question is, how do I access the first row only in `tmp`, which is the actual nodes in the network data?

When I do `tmp[1]`, it produces
`1e+14 
3388.23` where I only need 1e+14.

```
 dput(a)
 structure(c(3388.22995373249, 1493.16521374732, 1375.57742835837, 
 1350.68389440675, 1312.19704460178, 1302.44518389222), .Names = c("1e+14", 
 "5712365", "12815415", "511042", "12815383", "512594"))
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(tmp)` at the end of you question?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a named numeric vector as you can see below when using `str`.

```
str(a)
   Named num [1:6] 3388 1493 1376 1351 1312 ...
   - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "1e+14" "5712365" "12815415" "511042" ... 

#To select the 1st element 
a[1]
 1e+14 
 3388.23 

#To select the 1st element value without name
unname(a[1])
3388.23

#To select the 1st element name
names(a[1])
[1] "1e+14"
```

For all names/values in the vector, you can use `names(a)` / `unname(a)`.